# "float" object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am trying to find the mean of a list that contains the types int, float, and str. When I iterate through and print each item, the code works.

```
mylist = ["hello", 89.21, -3, "goodbye", 21, 0.0056, -12.34, "thank you", "please", 999.44409]
newlist = []
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
```

and the result is

```
hello
89.21
-3
goodbye
21
0.0056
-12.34
thank you
please
999.44409
```

But then when I try to operate on each "i" it gives me the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I am trying to iterate over each item, not each character.

```
    for i in mylist:
    if type(i)== int or type(i)== float:
        newlist += i
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in mylist: 
  if type(i)== int or type(i)== float:
    newlist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

the line

```
for i in myList
```

Means it goes through myList, or *iterates* through it.

example. if your string was `"hello"`,

and you did the += thing in the last line of the last snippet,

The newList would become `['h','e','l','l','o']`, which is not desired.

Floats aren't iterable, as stated in the Traceback (aka error message)

Therefore, you have to *append* the i into the new list that you want. That'll add it to the list.

So for that little snippet, you can do:

```
for i in mylist: 
    if type(i)== int or type(i)== float:
        newlist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem results from what happens when you try to add something to a list. Here is an example:

```
>>> i = []
>>> i += 'hello'
>>> i
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

You can see that when you try to add something to a list, each individual "item" of whatever is on the right of the `+=` operand is added separately to the list. This ability to separate an item into its components is called *iteration*, and when an object supports this we say the object is *iterable*.

The list object relies on this ability to iterate an object when trying to add things to a list.

Floats (and ints) are not iterable which is why you get the error. To fix the problem (as others have suggested), use the `append()` method, which just takes the item given in the argument and adds it as is to the list:

```
>>> i.append('hello')
>>> i
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'hello']
>>> i.append(10)
>>> i
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'hello', 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
newlist += i
```

with:

```
newlist += [i]
```

demo:

```
>>> [3.0] +4.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

>>> [3.0] + [4.0]
[3.0, 4.0]
```

you can also you `list.append` to append elements at the end of list

```
newlist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to do a `newlist += i`, python complains because this operation is valid only if `i` itself was a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?list#list) like `newlist` or any other iterable like a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#tuple). Then this operation would have combined the results and stored the result in `newlist`.

To add `i` to the `newlist`, you should use `newlist.append(i)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

newlist is a list here, Actually you are adding list reference with the value.

Instead of that, try this

```
newlist.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you are looking to check if the `type` is a `number` such as `int` or `float` while iterating then you'll want to use `isinstance`, doing something such as:

```
import numbers

mylist = ["hello", 89.21, -3, "goodbye", 21, 0.0056, -12.34, "thank you", "please", 999.44409]
newlist = []
for i in mylist:
    if isinstance(i, (int, float)):
        newlist += [i]
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[89.21, -3, 21, 0.0056, -12.34, 999.44409]
```